# 'int' never equal to null for 'char' variables

Tags: c#, variables, char, int, compiler-warnings

Can somebody answer me this - why do I get this warning "The result of the expression is always 'false' since a value of type 'int' is never equal to 'null' of type 'int?'"

Here is the code

```
    private char classLetter;
    public char ClassLetter
    {
        get { return classLetter; }
        set 
        {
            if (classLetter == null)
            {
                classLetter = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged("ClassLetter");
            }
            else throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException();
        }
    }
```

If I use this code no warning comes in

```
    private char classLetter;
    public char ClassLetter
    {
        get { return classLetter; }
        set 
        {
            if (classLetter.ToString() == null)
            {
                classLetter = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged("ClassLetter");
            }
            else throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException();
        }
    }
```

In short my question is this

How can a int warning be given for a char variable?

EDIT: The 'char' should hold any latin or Cyrillic Letter, no special symbols and no numbers allowed. How should that be filtered?

Comment: You can answer this yourself: Could `classLetter == null` ever be true? For what value of `classLetter`?

Comment: Do you want to write setter, which allows property to be set only once? Also, why don't you use `char?`, if you want to test, that property was set ever?

Comment: @usr well suppose I don't enter anything in a text box which corresponds to this field - then the field is left empty. From what I know that results in an null variable. Correct me if I'm wrong please

Comment: @Dennis I thought char was a nullable type so I did not see the logic of making it nullable

Comment: If you really want it to be null use "char?" instead of "char". Also read this ... http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x9h8tsay.aspx

Comment: @tweellt Thanks for the link, that explains why a warning is shown for int type and not for char

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the first case, `classLetter` is of type `char`, which can never be `null` because it's a value type; it would need to be of type `char?`. So comparing `classLetter == null` doesn't make sense, as the compiler says.

In the second case, imagine `classLetter` is `'x'`. When doing `classLetter.ToString()` you get `"x"`, which can be compared with `null` because it is now a reference type. But again, this is not what you want because `classLetter.ToString()` will never be `null`.

If what you want is allowing to set the value only once, you can do this:

```
private char? classLetter = null; // make it nullable
public char ClassLetter
{
    get {
        if(classLetter == null) { // if we don't have a value yet
            // do something, like throwing an exception
        }else{ // if we do have a value already
            return classLetter.Value; // here we return char, not char?
        }
    }
    set 
    {
        if (classLetter == null) {
            classLetter = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("ClassLetter");
        }
        else throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException();
    }
}
```

Comment: Ok that clarifies my question. I did not know that char was not a nullable type and thus has to be made nullable. Thanks for the quick response.

Answer (score 4):

A variable of type `char` is a value variable, not a reference variable, so it can never be `null`.  Only variables of reference types can be `null`.

Answer (score 1):

You get a warning because a value type will never be null. Full(er) explanation below.

A `char` in C# is a value type, and can never be null. Consider the purpose of `char`, that is to represent a Unicode character. There isn't really a good value to pick to mean `null` in the 0x0 to 0xFFFFFFFF range. (It's true that UTF-16 doesn't actually encompass this entire range, but it might someday).

It's a bit easy to understand with something that has a much smaller range. Consider a `byte`. It has a range of 0 - 255. Now, in order to represent `null`, we would need to pick a manner in which `null` could be stored. A few solutions end up coming up:

- Store information extra to the `byte` to represent null. `Nullable<Byte>` does this.
- Pick a value in the valid `byte` range to instead actually mean `null`. You end up needing to check for this value throughout an entire program. On a small scale, this is a non-issue, but when you don't know who's going to be using your code (a likely scenario), it's something you have to document and hope they see.

It's a much simpler implementation to provided non-nullable value types and a default and provide a wrapper around value types that can represent `null` if needed. .NET does exactly this with the `Nullable<T>` type and it's shortcuts with language support (`int?`,`byte?`, etc.).

To address your code, if `classLetter` really could be any value a `char` can represent, then you can use:

```
private char classLetter;
public char ClassLetter
{
    get { return classLetter; }
    set 
    {
        classLetter = value;
        RaisePropertyChanged("ClassLetter");
    }
}
```

You can do this because the compiler will give the user a compile-time error if they try to do something to `classLetter` they couldn't possibly do sanely.

If you have additional requirement about what `classLetter` is supposed to represent, update your question and I'll update my answer.

In reponse to your comment on another answer: "I want the behavior to be simple. I want to be able to put any symbol, but I don't want the variable to be left empty"

The only other thing we need to settle on is what "empty" really means. What does empty mean in your context? Once you answer that, you can use default initialization in the type containing `classLetter` to set it to that value. A generalized example:

```
class Foo {
  private char classLetter;
  public char ClassLetter {
    get { return classLetter; }
    set {
      classLetter = value;
    }
  }

  public Foo(char classLetter = 'A') {
    this.ClassLetter = classLetter;
  }
}
```

When a caller uses `new Foo()`, they will get a `Foo` instance where `Foo.ClassLetter == 'A'`. Of course, `A` can be any sensible default that meets your specific requirements.

Comment: I have one question - what happens if the user doesn't enter anything, what's the value of the 'char' variable then

Comment: It is _not possible_ to set a `char` to nothing (or `null`). `char` would be set to '\0', the null terminating character. Don't let the term null confuse you here - it's just a character that represents the end of a string, and happens to be a sensible default value for `char` to be initialized to.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want?

```
private char? classLetter;
public char ClassLetter
{
    get { return classLetter.Value; // this will throw exception, if value hasn't set }
    set 
    {
        if (classLetter != null)
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException("ClassLetter has been set already.");
        }

        classLetter = value;
        RaisePropertyChanged("ClassLetter");
    }
}
```

Note, that `ArgumentOutOfRangeException` doesn't fit this case. You don't make any tests for the *range* of argument.

Comment: Do I need to declare both char variables nullable or only the private one is enough. And I don't want the value to be set only once so why change the if(..) statement

Comment: @GeorgeAnastasov: do you confuse private field, property and variable? This is field: `private char? classLetter`. This is property: `public char ClassLetter`. To answer the question about `if`, you have to clarify the logic of your property. How it should behave? Your setter allows property to be set only once.

Comment: I want the behavior to be simple. I want to be able to put any symbol, but I don't want the variable to be left empty